# Hide text by padding when using overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set `overflow: hidden` so that it applies with padding set for the rectangle.

Here is an example: (HTML)

```
<div class="box-test">
   Stack Test Test Test sdf OverflowStack Test Test Test sdf OverflowStack Test 
   Test Test sdf OverflowStack Test Test Test sdf OverflowStack Test Test Test 
   sdf OverflowStack Test Test Test sdf OverflowStack Test Test Test sdf 
   OverflowStack Test Test Test sdf Overflow
</div>
```

(CSS)

```
.box-test {
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    background-color: green;
}
```

With the current implementation - padding applies to all sides except the bottom. What I am trying to achieve is have a padding in the bottom without trimming the text and using pesudo selectors such as `::before` and `::after`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-bottom

Comment: @Coder any specific reason that you don't want to use a pseudo selector?

Comment: @jburtondev because it will most probably be fixed for a size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a colomn-width equal to the width of your div, so :

```css
.box-test {
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    column-width:200px;
}
body {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-test">
    Stack Test Test Test sdf OverflowStack Test Test Test sdf OverflowStack Test 
    Test Test sdf OverflowStack Test Test Test sdf OverflowStack Test Test Test 
    sdf OverflowStack Test Test Test sdf OverflowStack Test Test Test sdf 
    OverflowStack Test Test Test sdf Overflow
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I would select this as an answer, however this looks to be more like a hack.

Comment: What are you saying about hack ?

Answer (score 1):

You're right about applying the padding to all side but then you declare a specific height (200px to be exact). And that is the reason why you cannot able to see the padding bottom. Try to set you height into (height: auto;). By this, your  can able to adapt in every text that you want to put inside of it.

Regarding about the overflow: hidden;
I don't really understand what you are trying to do here.